# keep getting javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId with jsf 2

Tags: jsf-2, shiro, commandbutton, viewexpiredexception

Whatever I do I get javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId. I know how to handle the exception (redirect to the main page again if I get the error), the issue is that any action I call from a commandButton is not executed.

Basically I have a simple view with a commandButton with an action.. I press it and I get the viewExpiredException or if I handle the error, I don't get the error messages but still my commandButton does not work.

I tried adding this:

```
 <context-param>
     <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
     <param-value>client</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

but it doesn't work. I don't know what is going on..

This is my view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    lang="es">
<div class="container">
    <h:form id="principal">
        <h1>Sistema de carga de publicaciones</h1>

        <h:outputText value="Ingrese el año por el que desea buscar publicaciones" />
        <h:inputText
            id="year"
            value="#{publicaciones.año}" />

        <h:commandButton
            style="display:block"
            id="boton-codigo-facultad"
            value="Buscar"
            type="submit">
        </h:commandButton>

        <h:panelGroup id="output">
            <h:outputText
                style="display:block"
                value="Total publicaciones en la DB:#{publicaciones.totalPublicacionesDB}" />
            <h:outputText
                style="display:block"
                value="Publicaciones obtenidas desde el WS:" />
            <h:outputText
                style="display:block"
                value="Publicaciones nuevas:" />
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:commandButton
            style="display:block"
            id="insertar"
            value="Cargar publicacion"
            action="#{insert.insertPublicacionDB}">
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</div>
</html>
```

backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="insert")
@ViewScoped
public class comparaDatosBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Map<String, Object> parametros=new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object> params2=new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("pase por aqui!!");
    }

    public void insertPublicacionDB() throws SQLException {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
        ControllerPublicacion controlador= (ControllerPublicacion) applicationContext.getBean("controllerPublicaciones");
        parametros.put("ut","234567876545555");
        parametros.put("py", 2013);

        params2.put("ut", "234567876545555");
        params2.put("bp","asjñldfkjsñd");
        params2.put("la", "Español");
        params2.put("ti","Publicacion de prueba");
        params2.put("py",2013);
        params2.put("sn", "234wf");
        params2.put("di", "asdfsf");
        params2.put("j9", "");
        params2.put("dt", "");
        params2.put("ga", "");
        params2.put("dt", "");
        params2.put("so", "");
        params2.put("fx", "");
        params2.put("ep", "");
        params2.put("issue", "");
        params2.put("parte","");
        params2.put("vl", "");
        params2.put("rp", "");
        params2.put("vinculada", null);
        params2.put("ji", "");
        params2.put("pd","");
        params2.put("pg", "");
        params2.put("pa","");
        params2.put("ab","");
        params2.put("pi", "");
        params2.put("numero_articulo", null);
        params2.put("tipo_carga_revista",null);
        params2.put("id",null );
        params2.put("su", "");
        System.out.println(params2.get("la"));
        if(controlador.existeEnDB(parametros)>0){
            System.out.println("La publicacion ya existe en la Base de Datos");
        } else {
            controlador.insertPublicacion(params2);
            System.out.println("la publicacion ha sido añadida");
        }

    }

    public Map<String, Object> getParametros() {
        return parametros;
    }

    public void setParametros(Map<String, Object> parametros) {
        this.parametros = parametros;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getParams2() {
        return params2;
    }

    public void setParams2(Map<String, Object> params2) {
        this.params2 = params2;
    }

}
```

Error message:

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/test] threw exception [viewId:/main.jsf - No se pudo restablecer la vista /main.jsf.] with root cause
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/main.jsf - No se pudo restablecer la vista /main.jsf.
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:212)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:110)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

What I need is to know why this is happening, not how to handle the exception.. I can't call any action from a commandButton because nothing happens.

Comment: your first `commandButton` has no `action` attribute, so this one for sure won't call your backing bean. The other one should though. Actually it did on my local working example... Do you have any error message (either browser or java console)?

Comment: i know my first commandButton does not have an action.. is just there lol... and i'll post my full error message now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it with this:

```
 <context-param>
     <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
     <param-value>client</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

In some places I saw it like this `javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING` but it did not work.

Comment: Is there any security implications in saving the state on the client?

Comment: @jrobertsz66 if you can make sense of very long hashed and encoded (and possibly encrypted) strings in your html containing the view state that'd otherwise be maintained on the server, you could in theory modify them and send other data to the server. Good luck :)